# Abstracting the accountcontroller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, interface, abstract-class

How would I go about abstracting the membership information in MVC3 c#

Currently the membership data is kept on a localhost SQL server and is linked to MVC via the Entity Framework.

As I want to perform some extensions, I need to abstract it, creating an interface and class for each entity in the SQL database?

Where would I start? Are there any examples available? I can only find ones that are out of date or irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rearrange your application, introducing a service layer separated from your presentation layer. The object model (domain model) that you define in the presentation layer for User and other entities should be distinct from the EF data model, so you need only that some sevices ( for example you can implement these as Web Services) read the data using EF and populate your domain model of the presentataion layer.
This approach allows your application to be more flexible to future changes or extensions.